# Adding a feature for unseen words

Tags: matrix, scikit-learn

I am using sklearn countvectorizer to build my term-document matrix

However,

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(min_df=1)
corpus = ['this is jummy speaking now']
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
c = vectorizer.transform(['lol 123']).toarray()
```

What happens is that X would be a term document matrix of 5 words. However,  i would like the matrix to have an unknown column aka term document matrix of 6 words. In the case when a new unseen word is found, i would like it to be part of the unknown column. like for example (lol and 123) is not in the corpus. It should be part of the unknown column.

Comment: It's not directly possible to do in `scikit`. I'm pretty sure it doesn't make sense to do this though, what are you intending to do with your vectors?

Comment: Unknown words could be a feature that I am exploring

Comment: If you are intending to perform learning on these vectors then it doesn't make sense. Your training set will contain no instances of unseen words, so any model trained on those data will be useless at making any predictions based on unseen words.

Comment: Let's say I drop words that occur less than x times in the corpus. This would give me the unknown word vector